# What is the exact way of doing fast on Shivratri?

Tags: shiva, fasting

When i asked people about fast on Shivratri, I did not get satisfactory answers. Different people believe different ways. 
I want to know the proper way of fasting on shivrari.

Is that true that you can get your desired life partner if you do it in a proper way?

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "proper" way.Fasting is abstaining from food and water(in case of nirjala fast).Its upto you whether you can give up food and water for one whole day(day and night i mean).Once you have determined that you will do the fast,wake up in early hours on that day(before sunrise is recommended).Take bath etc,wear fresh clothes and pray to Lord Shiva so that you can complete the fast successfully.Fast of Shivaratri is also associated with a keeping vigil for the entire night.Devotees don't sleep that whole night...

Comment: Now coming to the Puja part-Usually puja is done throughout the day but pujas at the night are important.Each nite is divided into 4 prahars(3 hour for each prahar start counting from sunset).Lord Shiva is "Avieskha Priya" (one who loves to bath).So avisekhams are also done for 4 times in each prahar.But the most important puja in Sivaratri is the one falling in what is called the "Nisitha Kala" muhurtam.For my place this muhurta falls on 11 22 PM (duration of this muhutam is 48 mins).Another vital thing is breaking the fast which is on the next day (ie Tuesday)

Comment: Breaking of fast is done ONLY in a time period known as the parana time.For my place this time lasts till (aprox) 10 30 AM(on tuesday) staring from the sunrise time.Breaking of any fast should only be done  after taking a bath.You should check local panchangam for correct Nisitha Kala puja time and also the parana time for your place.If you dont know how to do puja just take a note of the parana time .Breaking of fast on tuesday should be done in this time period only.

Comment: Use [this](http://www.drikpanchang.com/festivals/maha-shivaratri/maha-shivaratri-date-time.html) site to know muhurtas at your place.

Comment: Also see [this](http://www.drikpanchang.com/tables/choghadiya.html?date=07/03/2016) .

Comment: @AnilKumar i also follow that site.Its the best one i feel for the purpose. :)

Answer (score 2):

> Following Puja Vidhi during Maha Shivaratri has been collected from
>   various religious texts. We have included all main rituals which are
>   suggested during Maha Shivaratri.
>
> - It is suggested to have only single meal a day before Maha Shivaratri    fasting. It is one of the common practices during
>     fasting to make    sure any undigested food is not left in the
>     digestion system on the    fasting day.
> - On the day of Shivaratri, one should get up early in the morning and    take bath. It is suggested to add black sesame seeds into the
>     water.    It is believed that the holy bath on the day of Shivaratri
>     purifies    not only the body but also the soul. If possible bathing
>     in Ganges is    preferred.
> - After taking bath devotees should take Sankalp (संकल्प) to observe    full day fast and to break the fast on the next day. During Sankalp
>     devotees pledge for self-determination throughout the fasting period
>     and seek blessing of Lord Shiva to finish the fast without any
>     interference. Hindu fasts are strict and people pledge for
>     self-determination and seek God blessing before starting them to
>     finish them successfully.
> - Devotees should abstain from all type of food during the fasting. In    the strict form of fasting even water is not allowed. However,
>     consumption of fruits and milk is suggested during day time which
>     should be followed by strict fasting during night. In other words
>     during day time fruits and milk can be consumed.
> - Devotees should take second bath in the evening before doing Shiva    Puja or visiting temple. If one is not able to visit the temple then
>     makeshift Shiva Ling can be made to perform Puja activities. One can
>     even shape the mud in Linga form and apply Ghee to perform Abhishek
>     Puja at home.
> - Shiva Puja should be done during night. Shivaratri Puja can be    performed one time or four times during the night. The whole night
>     duration can be divided into four to get four Prahar (प्रहर) to
>     perform Shiva Puja four times. Devotees who want to perform single
>     Puja should do it during midnight.
> - As per Puja Vidhi, Abhishek of Shiva Lingam should be performed with    different materials. The milk, rose water, sandalwood paste,
>     yogurt,    honey, Ghee, sugar and the water are commonly used for
>     Abhishek.    Devotees, who perform four Prahar Puja, must perform
>     water Abhishek    during first Prahar, curd Abhishek during second
>     Prahar, Ghee    Abhishek during third Prahar and honey Abhishek during
>     fourth Prahar    apart from other materials.
> - After the Abhishek ritual, Shiva Linga is adorned with the garland    made of Bilva leaves. It is believed that Bilva leaves cool down Lord 
>     Shiva.
> - After that Chandan or Kumkum is applied to the Shiva Linga which is    followed by lighting lamp and Dhupa. The other items which are used
>     to adorn Lord Shiva include flower of Madar (मदार) which is also
>     known as Aak (आक), Vibhuti which is also known as Bhasm. Vibhuti is
>     sacred ash which is made using dried cow dung.
> - The mantra to chant during Puja duration is ॐ नमः शिवाय (Om Namah    Shivaya).
> - Devotees should break the fast next day after taking bath. Devotees    should break the fast between sunrise and before the end of
>     Chaturdashi Tithi to get maximum benefit of the Vrat.

[Source](http://www.drikpanchang.com/festivals/maha-shivaratri/maha-shivaratri-puja-vidhi.html)

Answer (score 1):

The Mahashivratri fasting begins on the morning of Shivratri and ends next day morning or the Amavasya morning. Since it is a long Upvaas or Vrat, many people consume a special meal known as ‘phalar.’ The fasting involves refraining from eating any food and not sleeping through out the night.

> 1. It is suggested to have only single meal a day before Maha Shivaratri fasting. It is one of the common practices during fasting
>      to make sure any undigested food is not left in the digestion system
>      on the fasting day.
> 2. On the day of Shivaratri, one should get up early in the morning and take bath. It is suggested to add black sesame seeds into the
>      water. It is believed that the holy bath on the day of Shivaratri
>      purifies not only the body but also the soul. If possible bathing in
>      Ganges is preferred.
> 3. After taking bath devotees should take Sankalp (संकल्प) to observe full day fast and to break the fast on the next day. During Sankalp
>      devotees pledge for self-determination throughout the fasting period
>      and seek blessing of Lord Shiva to finish the fast without any
>      interference. Hindu fasts are strict and people pledge for
>      self-determination and seek God blessing before starting them to
>      finish them successfully.
> 4. Devotees should abstain from all type of food during the fasting. In the strict form of fasting even water is not allowed. However,
>      consumption of fruits and milk is suggested during day time which
>      should be followed by strict fasting during night. In other words
>      during day time fruits and milk can be consumed.
> 5. Devotees should take second bath in the evening before doing Shiva Puja or visiting temple. If one is not able to visit the temple then
>      makeshift Shiva Ling can be made to perform Puja activities. One can
>      even shape the mud in Linga form and apply Ghee to perform Abhishek
>      Puja at home.
> 6. Shiva Puja should be done during night. Shivaratri Puja can be performed one time or four times during the night. The whole night
>      duration can be divided into four to get four Prahar (प्रहर) to
>      perform Shiva Puja four times. Devotees who want to perform single
>      Puja should do it during midnight.
> 7. As per Puja Vidhi, Abhishek of Shiva Lingam should be performed with different materials. The milk, rose water, sandalwood paste,
>      yogurt, honey, Ghee, sugar and the water are commonly used for
>      Abhishek. Devotees, who perform four Prahar Puja, must perform water
>      Abhishek during first Prahar, curd Abhishek during second Prahar, Ghee
>      Abhishek during third Prahar and honey Abhishek during fourth Prahar
>      apart from other materials.
> 8. After the Abhishek ritual, Shiva Linga is adorned with the garland made of Bilva leaves. It is believed that Bilva leaves cool down Lord
>      Shiva.
> 9. After that Chandan or Kumkum is applied to the Shiva Linga which is followed by lighting lamp and Dhupa. The other items which are used to
>      adorn Lord Shiva include flower of Madar (मदार) which is also known as
>      Aak (आक), Vibhuti which is also known as Bhasm. Vibhuti is sacred ash
>      which is made using dried cow dung.
> 10. The mantra to chant during Puja duration is ॐ नमः शिवाय (Om Namah Shivaya).
> 11. Devotees should break the fast next day after taking bath. Devotees should break the fast between sunrise and before the end of
>       Chaturdashi Tithi to get maximum benefit of the Vrat.

[Source](http://www.drikpanchang.com/festivals/maha-shivaratri/maha-shivaratri-puja-vidhi.html)

**food we can eat while observing Shivaratri Fast**

> Majority of Hindus who observe Shivratri fast opt for a fruit diet –
>   they eat fruits and drink lots of water on the day. Some people also
>   drink milk.
>
> Some devotees consume a mid-day meal (noon) consisting of non-cereal
>   food such as boiled potatoes which is made into a curry without onion,
>   garlic, adarak (ginger) or haldi (turmeric).
>
> In some regions people eat Sabudana (Tapioca) Khichdi or Upma.
>
> Some Hindu communities eat a special meal known as ‘phalar’ at noon.
>
> Another food eaten on the day is pakori or Kutt Singahri ki puri.
>
> No meal is eaten after sunset on Shivaratri day.
>
> Next meal is taken on the morning of Amavasya (next day morning) after
>   doing puja and giving alms.

[Source](http://www.hindu-blog.com/2010/02/shivratri-food-what-food-we-can-eat.html)